# print selected row from datagridview Error

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

i am using this code to print selected row from datagridview & I receive This Error (Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.)

```
Me.salesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ordersDataSet.sales)
    Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView.RowFilter = "id='" &
    Form1.SalesDataGridView.Item(1, Form1.SalesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value &
    "'"
    salesBindingSource.DataSource = Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the **''**.

```
Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("id={0}", Form1.SalesDataGridView.Item(1, Form1.SalesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value)
```

If the column/field is nullable you could do:

```
Dim value As Object = Me.SalesDataGridView.Item(1, Me.SalesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value

If ((value Is Nothing) OrElse ((TypeOf value Is DBNull) OrElse ((TypeOf value Is System.Data.SqlTypes.INullable) AndAlso DirectCast(value, System.Data.SqlTypes.INullable).IsNull))) Then
    Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[id] IS NULL"
Else
    Dim id As Integer = System.Convert.ToInt32(value)
    Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[id]={0}", id)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks For Replay .. I Try You Suggest And Recive This Error (Syntax error: Missing operand after '=' operator. )

Comment: It my be due to a null value. I will edit the answer.

Comment: FYI: `Me.SalesDataGridView.Item(1, N)` is actually referring to the second column of the DataGridView. (Just if you don't know it uses zero-based indexing.)

Comment: perfect . thank you . worked ok with your first code and i change 1 to 0         Me.ordersDataSet.sales.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("id={0}", Form1.SalesDataGridView.Item(0, Form1.SalesDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value)